# MySQL (MariaDB) float visualization: why are values rounded to hundreds or thousands?

Tags: mysql, floating-accuracy

First: I am a MySql newbie and it looks like I am missing something important here.

In a MySQL database my float values range from units to billions.
I spent days trying to understand why all of them showed no more than 6 significant digits with the less significant ones set to 0:

i.e.:

```
select `field` from `table`;
(instead of X -> i get Y)
  1 -> 1
  12 -> 12
  123 -> 123
  1234 -> 1234
  12345 -> 12345
  123456 -> 123456
  1234567 -> 1234570
  12345678 -> 12345700
  123456789 -> 123457000
```

Only with a "trick" I found somewhere I could read the real values:

```
select `field`+0.0 from `table`;
```

My questions: what is the rationale behind this (imho) strange behavior? and where is it described in the documentation?
I find completely non-intuitive that I don't see the real value (of course approximated according to IEEE specifications) with the normal select * but I need the trick... What am I missing here?

Comment: Could you please show a [mcve], e.g. copy/paste a complete MySQL session from table creation through to data selection?  Perhaps even demonstrate with a [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) if the output formatting there permits demonstration of this problem?

Comment: @eggyal, here is the minimal example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/352bf/1/0

From ID6 the result is rounded to 6 meaningful cyphers. The problem is that with "select *" by default I will normally see the rounded value, not the real one...

I assume there is  a command to set the db to use the "real" value instead, but cannot understand what is the reason of this strange developer choice.

Comment: Just tried on SQLfiddle: using _double_ instead of _float_ works perfectly.

Comment: @RyanVincent, I can imagine the behavior is related to the number of decimals, but I found appalling to change even the integer side of a number and keep only 6 meaningful cyphers by default.
My knowledge of Mysql is minimal (my fault, I am sure that this is stated in every mysql book) but I can assume there are a lot of newbies like me that didn't see that the data they are using are plain wrong.

Comment: @RyanVincent, I gave a look at IEEE754 and the mantissa for a float is just too short to represent more than 6 exact digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- A `FLOAT` has 24 bits, or `log10(224)` (over 7) digits, of significance: `12345678.910` is stored in a `FLOAT` as `1011110001100001010011112` (which is `1234567910`).  When displaying as decimal, the client knows *for certain* that everything from the 8th digit onwards is *definitely* [false precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_precision) (since a `FLOAT` was only capable of storing 7 decimal digits of precision).  It therefore discards the remainder, leaving you with `12345680`.
- A `DOUBLE` has 53 bits, or `log10(253)` (almost 16) digits, of significance: `12345678.910` is stored in a `DOUBLE` as `101111000110000101001110.111001100110011001100110011012` (which is `12345678.9000000003710`).  When displaying as decimal, the client knows *for certain* that everything from the 16th digit onwards is *definitely* [false precision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_precision) (since a `DOUBLE` was only capable of storing 15 decimal digits of precision).  It therefore discards the remainder, leaving you with `12345678.9000000`.

When adding `+0.0`, MySQL first casts the `FLOAT` up to a `DOUBLE`.

Comment: Thank you @eggyal. I was writing the very same when I received your answer. The problem is that I overlooked the IEEE754 representation as you noted.
Even forcing the double conversion with +0.0 I read the extra cyphers but as they have been saved as float, are of course not precise.
Thank you.

Comment: @AlexPoca: Actually, what's interesting is that you appear to be (unnecessarily) losing a decimal digit along the way.  Whilst the mantissa of a `FLOAT` occupies only 23 bits of storage, the most significant bit is not stored explicitly so you do have in fact 24 bits (or 7 digits) of significance as stated in my answer.  If there were only 23 bits of significance, there would be insufficient information to guarantee the correctness of the 7th digit—and consequently one would have to drop that too.  It seems that the decimal conversion is erroneously assuming 23 instead of 24 bits: a bug.

Answer (score 0):

I overlooked the representation of float and double according to IEEE754 and that is the solution of this mystery.

FLOAT (32 bit) has a mantissa of 23 bits (8 millions possible values => 6 meaningful digits), the other 9 bits are used for sign and exponent.
DOUBLE (64 bit) has a mantissa of 52 bits (some 4.5e15 possible values => 14 meaningful digits).

That means Mysql cannot show something that is not there (in my case FLOAT big numbers) and fills the "random" not meaningful digits with zeros.